# Monodroid JNIEnv.FindClass from library

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

In Monodroid I'm trying to access a custom Java class through JNIEnv.  When I add the class in the main project I can access it in the main project and in a library project.

For example:
If jniTest.java is an AndroidJavaSource file in Project A then

```
IntPtr javaClass = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/company/application/jniTest");
```

works from both Project A and from Library B.  However if I change it so that I take the same file and rename the class to jniText in Library B then I cannot access it in Library B with

```
IntPtr javaClass = JNIEnv.FindClass("com/company/application/jniText");
```

The reason I say I have to rename the file because if I move the file to Library B such that it's not in Project A anymore calling the FindClass will still find jniTest even though it's in the library.  I believe it still finds it in the original location.  This led me to believe that when I moved the java file to my library that it was working fine.  It was only after a namespace change did it stop working because now the original that was somehow still built into Project A was now not the same as what was in Library B causing the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I'm hoping I just missed a project attribute or JNIEnv method but I can't find what to set to make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only AndroidJavaSource, AndroidAsset, AndroidResource, etc. that are in your main project will make it into the final package.  These things are not supported in library projects.

Comment: Do you know if there's a technical reason or just something the team hasn't gotten around to doing?

Comment: Well, it's a technical reason that we haven't gotten around to it yet.  It's kinda like trying to make a UI library for ASP.Net, the end result of a library compile is a .dll, which doesn't include things like images or .css.  At the end of the library compile, we just have the compiled .dll, we don't know that it had a .java referenced.  This can be fixed by stuffing the .java into a .net resource in the library, and then pulling it out in the MFA app project and compiling it.  So it's possible, just requires a bit of work that hasn't been done yet.

Comment: Is this feature on the MonoTouch roadmap? It's a pity it doesn't work as It'd be nice to package up the Java source with it's C# wrapper and hide it away.